# Validate form and some inputs at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Here I have a form and I need to validate form. I have select2 input fields and this fields I cant validate with parsley plugin so I write my code...

Problem is how to at same time check if `validate = true` and select2 `inputs ===null`...

I write:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( $(this).parsley('validate') ) {                
            if ($("#parcele").select2("data")== null || $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data")== null) {
                $('#parerror').show();
                console.log('nema dalje');
            } else {                
                var zemljiste = $("#parcele").select2("data").naziv;
                var id_parcele = $("#parcele").select2("data").id;
                var vrsta_rada = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data").text;    

                $.ajax({
                    url: "insertAkt.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true, 
                    data: { naziv:$("#naziv").val(),parcele:zemljiste,vrsta_rada:vrsta_rada,opis:$("#opis").val(),pocetak:$("#pocetak").val(),zavrsetak:$("#zavrsetak").val(),status:$("#status").val(),id_parcele:id_parcele,}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
                    dataType: "html",

                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        drawVisualization();
                        console.log('USPEH'); 
                        console.log(data);  
                    }, 
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

but as you can see my code first check form validation after that select2 inputs so how I can at same time check form and select2 inputs fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using && operator you can check both condition at the same time

if ( ($(this).parsley('validate')) && ($("#parcele").select2("data") === null)) {
}

Comment: hm, I cant show error on select2 fields at same time ?